# I have a complication about Python's for in loop

Tags: python, for-loop, for-in-loop

I wanted to create a program which understands the famous quote you write and shows the words which have a first letter higher than "g" but I constantly ran into some complications. Here is 2 codes I tried:

So here is my first code;

```
quote=input("Please input your quotes sentence.")
word=""

for letter in quote:
    if word=="":
        word=word+letter
    elif word.lower().isalpha():
        word=word+letter
    elif word.lower().isalpha()==False:
        if word[0].lower()>="h":
            print(word.upper())
            word=""
        else:
            word=""
```

And my second code;

```
for letter in quote:
    if letter.lower().isalpha():
        word=word+letter.lower()
    elif letter.lower().isalpha()==False:
        if letter.lower()>= "h":
            print(word.upper())
            word=""
        elif letter.lower()<"h":
            word=""
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question here? Solving your puzzle? Pointing you in the right direction? Also if you want to take the words which have first letter before 'g', then why are you checking to see if the first letter is "bigger" than h? Isn't that everything AFTER h and not before? `if letter.lower()>= "h":`

Comment: My mistake i wanted them to be higher than g.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if I understand your question right, but what about something like this:

```
# Input your quote here
quote = "A very import quote goes here"
out = [] # The output buffer

# Iterate over all words (seperated by <<space>>)
for word in quote.split(" "):
    if word[0].lower() < "g": out += [word]


print (" ".join(out))
```

Above code will print "A" because its the only word that starts with a letter smaller than "g".

Comment: I'm quite sure that he wanted to print out the whole quote that starts with a letter before G.

Comment: I want the program to identify the words that have first letter higher than g, then list them in capital while ignoring the other words. I hope this is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Juliusmh was near, but not exactly what you wanted. As you wanted the whole word to be printed out (not just the first letter thats before G), here you go:

```
# Input your quote here
quote = "A very import quote goes here"
out = "" # The output buffer

# Iterate over all words (seperated by <<space>>)
for word in quote.split(" "):
    if word[0].lower() < "g": out += quote + " "


print (out)
```

Comment: I want the program to identify the words that have first letter higher than g, then list them in capital while ignoring the other words. I hope this is more clear,

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after chromaerrors answer, i changed the variable "quote" in the 7th column to word and my problem has been solved. The code is this:

```
quote = input("A very import quote goes here")
out = [] # The output buffer

# Iterate over all words (seperated by <<space>>)
for word in quote.split(" "):
    if word[0].lower() < "g": out += word + " "


print ("".join(out))
```

And the output lists all the words which have starting letter lower than g.

Thanks for all the help. :)

Comment: Could you accept @chromaerror's answer because it is basically the same. Great you could solve the problem anyways.